# Localization not working in input placeholder

Tags: jquery, localization, language-translation

I'm using [Jquery localize](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize) for localization.

The text in the placeholder attribute not changing.

Here is my code:

```
 <input type="text" id="qty"  data-translate="input" placeholder="Qty">
```

And the language json code:

```
{
   "input" : {
        "Qty" : "Quantity"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

**Use value field ,Its working for me.**

```
"login": {
    "unm": {
        "value": "User name"
    }
}

<input data-localize="login.unm" type="text" name="user_name" value="" placeholder="User Name" />
```

Comment: Its worked for me, but I don't understand why **value** is used instead of **placeholder**

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
   {
   "input" : {
        "Qty" : "Quantity"
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
   "input" : {
        "placeholder" : "Quantity"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consult the documentation, you'll find that this is how you should do it:

```
<input type="text" id="qty" data-localize="input.Qty">
```